# Drag and Drop load content html or load DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

As shown in my attachment, I need, when I drag the 1 to 0, then 0 will be replaced by the number 1, and load the content text in the content area, 2 3 4 the same, load corresponding content, sorry my english not good

http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw3932677476163280247/2136498171

I dont have 10 reputation, i cant upload image

Comment: No image being shown. Also, please see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I dont have 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: good old days when i dont have enough rep I used http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw you can try as well :)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: This link http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw3932677476163280247/2136498171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the things you want to drag draggable by giving them the attribute draggable="true".  So those boxes that contain the numbers - you either want to make the whole box have draggable=true or if just the number, wrap it in a span and make that draggable.

Once they are draggable, you want to set the dataTransfer object like so (supposing there is nothing else except the number in the thing being dragged):

```
ondragstart = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.innerHTML);
}
```

For things that can be dropped - you need to cancel the dragover event to indicate a drop is allowed, much has been written about this, but in essence you want something like :

```
$(".dropTargets").bind("dragover", function(ev) {
    event.preventDefault(); // or something like that
});
```

Finally get the drop event :

```
$(".target").bind("drop", function(ev) {
    this.innerHTML = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
});
```

here is a very quick sample showing how it works : http://jsfiddle.net/zcZE5/2/

A couple implementation details that will save you some sweat here is that you

a) You need to call setData otherwise firefox will not start the drag
b) You must use the key "text" otherwise IE will complain.

Comment: HI Woody, My draw update http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw3932677476163280247/2136498171, the same your demo, i need, whe drop number 1 into box target, content number 1 load into box content, the same 2 3 4 5, thanks